# Likelihood of histories given state space, initial distribution, transition matrix

Tags: markov-chains

I'm an economist looking at Markov Chains for the first time, and this is simple stuff and it is quite embarassing to post about this, because the answer is provided, but I do not understand the solution to the problem below. Can someone shed some lights on this (the exercise is in the link)?

[Sargent and Ljunqvist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M81PG.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? A basic theorem in the theory of Markov chains is that $(X_n)$ is Markov on a countable state space $S$ with transition matrix with entries $p_{ij}$ and initial distribution $\pi$ if and only if for any $N+1$ states, $i_0,\dotsc,i_N$, the following equation holds: $$P(X_0=i_0,\dotsc, X_N=i_N)=\pi_{i_0}p_{i_0 i_1} \cdot \dotso \cdot p_{i_{N-1} i_N},$$ which is exactly what they state and use to calculate the probability of a given path of states.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I can see it now. It's blindingly obvious, actually. Either lack of sleep or a dumb moment...